# Image not displaying properly using the most popular jpeg-decoder in rust

Tags: rust, jpeg, decode, gdi

Simply trying to decode jpg data to bmp and display the result on screen using Windows GDI. Image did show on screen with correct size but looks mono and quite broken. I don't know how to debug this. Could be problem with the decoder? Code and the images below.

```rust
use jpeg_decoder as jpeg;
use winsafe;

fn show_img() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        
        //img_data contains the jpg file data:

    let buff = std::io::Cursor::new(img_data);
    let mut decoder = jpeg::Decoder::new(buff);  //using the most popular decoder in rust crates
    let mut pixels = decoder.decode().expect("failed to decode image");
    let metadata = decoder.info().unwrap();
    let h_bmp = winsafe::HBITMAP::CreateBitmap(
           SIZE::new(metadata.width as i32, metadata.height as i32), 
       1, 32, pixels.as_mut_ptr())?;           // bmPlanes=1, bmBitsPixel=32
    
    let mut bitmap = winsafe::BITMAP{
        bmType: 0,
        bmWidth: 0,
        bmHeight: 0,
        bmWidthBytes: 0,
        bmPlanes: 0,
        bmBitsPixel: 0,
        bmBits: std::ptr::null_mut(),
    };
    h_bmp.GetObject(&mut bitmap)?;
    let h_dc = HDC::NULL.CreateCompatibleDC()?;
    let _g_bmp = h_dc.SelectObject(&*h_bmp)?;
    let dhwnd = HWND::GetDesktopWindow();  //Get the Screen and display
    let h_ddc = dhwnd.GetDC()?;
    let deskd = dhwnd.GetClientRect()?;
    h_ddc.BitBlt(POINT::new((deskd.right-bitmap.bmWidth)/2, 0),
        SIZE::new(bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight),
                &h_dc,POINT::new(0, 0),co::ROP::SRCCOPY)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

The broken image:

[image: broken]

Original image:

[image: original]

Code run through but I can't tell which part went wrong.

Comment: Your bmp expects 32-bits per pixel, but doesn't `jpeg::decode` produce 24-bits per pixel output?

Comment: ot: `use winsafe;` does exactly nothing.